# Typescript: nested generics unable to be correctly inferred?

Tags: typescript

This is my type:

```
type Person = {
  name: string;
  age: number;
};
type Recordable = Record<string, number | string | boolean>;
interface Column<T extends Recordable> {
  data: T;
  dataIndex?: string | number;
}
interface MyColumn<T extends Recordable> extends Column<T> {
  dataIndex: keyof T; // Error: Type 'keyof T' is not assignable to type 'string | number | undefined'.
}
```

TS compiler says this type 'keyof T' is not assignable to type 'string | number | undefined'.

Example: [ts playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgArQM4HsTIN4BQyxyIcAthAFzIZhSgDmA3ESXI9aQK7kBG0VgF8CYAJ4AHFACUICLFAAmcPgBsUAXmSz5SgDx0GIRgBoe-aMgA%20tek2vI%20WLOrggAfK1CRYiFAGEXXhA9ABVkCAAPSBBFDG05BWU1CHd8NmJlMDgaUNYSZCy4AElYqIB%20GkN7GxBeAShhAm9oeCRkAFkxQNVgsIjoiFj4nSSVdTSomLjkHr7QtMICotLFKJoAawgxLBhkPIIReRA6ZAArRA2aLrnyEPQobA9kLSWSIpo8UgouAHIAKUuvzMHC4AEZkEITBlCnBsqt1shfqDgYdmEA)

Of cause I can refactor it:

```
interface MyColumn<T extends Recordable> extends Omit<Column<T>, 'dataIndex'> {
  dataIndex: keyof T;
}
```

But, this will cause 'dataIndex' to not be constrained by Column.

And I want to constrain the value of "dataIndex" to be properties of "Person", like this:

```
const jack: MyColumn<Person> = {
  data: { name: 'Jack', age: 1 },
  dataIndex: 'name', // name, age
};
```

---

Update:

I had refactored the code, please see [ts playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgArQM4HsTIN4BQyyIcAthAFzIZhSgDmA3EcnA1SQK5kBG0LYhxAATaAH5qteiGYEAvgQJgAngAcUAJQgIsUEXF4AbFAF5k23foA80xgBoadRsgA+3PtDfJeWLCbgQAD4WAlBIWEQUAGF-HhBrABVkCAAPSFEMCx09A2MIIPxWAzA4akTBZBK4AElRNMknGQZvEB5+KBZFMPBoeCRkAFkVWKN4pJT0iEzsqzyTQrSMkSzR8cTCwmJqurFU6gBRdKhEMGsAawgVLBhkRMc7WRCFJQB6V8nyNRNkAEZldQodBQbAgRKA5DmVDABDnazA0GOS7XW4InDPAi6EC0ZAIAAWcCgqCgWDU1GGazICTRYMBhXMWyqcFK1DwJHInAA5AApRDnTmOdicX7IeT2YrM2r1fbITlCgUKULvT5kb4oABMADp-qoNGhCWBgHAjMTSRgJktpis0DC4TTHJzSBROUF6UMRnEqUkMVicWoDUajNECUSSWT9VBDcbTWpzdDYfDMDgHU6IC63Yzqqz2RRqDy+ZzReLtpLdmk86mFfIlR80l8flr1QQYFwQAhDThkBwwMHCTHKQlkpaZvG7UmQCmOemABRZu4ASnJHrGXo2RWIUAgYC4UFwjJLLKZpWLxGQyp20orU7YWSOdFOFyuNzuD2cTxPB6leyvzscyoOUAklA5QQpyjwMIWwBZCAWBgDeGDAAwpD5MgYBYKhoF3ic7aPiiL5NIwQSsNWLzdr2oakgO8K2omILJrKlbeHKHAzmyqZ5rysICmwHDUCK8jziwQA).

I converted the `interface` to a `type`, and specified the type of `dataIndex` as `string` using `Extract`. However, in example 2.2, `dataIndex` prompts `Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Extract<keyof T, string>'`, but in example 2.1, it's ok. In this case, is it impossible to infer whether `Extract<keyof T, string>` is `string` or `never`?

---

Update 1:

Using an intersection type, without modifying the `Column`, can resolve the issue of 'dataIndex' being not assignable to type in the `getCharPropColumn`.

```
interface MyColumn<T extends Recordable> extends Column<T> {
  dataIndex: keyof T & Exclude<Column<T>['dataIndex'], undefined>;
}
```

Complete here [ts playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgArQM4HsTIN4BQyyIcAthAFzIZhSgDmA3EcnA1SQK5kBG0LYhxAATaAH5qteiGYEAvgQJgAngAcUAJQgIsUEXF4AbFAF5k23foA80xgBoadRsgA%203PtDfJeWLCbgQAD4WAlBIWEQUAGF-HhBrABVkCAAPSFEMCx09A2MIIPxWAzA4akTBZBK4AElRNMknGQZvEB5%20KBZFMPBoeCRkAFkVWKN4pJT0iEzsqzyTQrSMkSzR8cTCwmIAem2quFK6sVTqAFF0qEQwawBrCBUsGGRExzWyBI2AbQByaqO074AXRCxQOtXqJ2QdweT2SADJkOcEGMxNY3h8gj8-hCgY4uPUYKAICIQd1dpNyGoTMgAIzKdQodBQbAgRIM5DmVDABA3axMlmOaGPNCYHAggi6EC0ZAIAAWcCgqCgWDU1GG6L5otZDMK5i2%201K1DwJHInG%20AClEDdvo52Jwach5PZQYcIdRvnabQpQuS0pTqQAmAB0dNUGjQCrAwDgRiVKowEyW0xWaG5vP5OEc31IFG%20QV1QxGcXeSXFkulakj0aM0XliuVqojUCjMbjagTXJ5muZmeQ2dNeYL%20uqRpNFHdlp530dzuI2OO7pzEC98h9ez9ZCpKGDAYIMHxCCjOGQHDAtYVbY1ySTM076a1WaXg4AFCPngBKNVFsYljZFYhQBAYBcFAuD6nOYLUNUs7EAa4ILn2T6OOSwBgN8WRYDcrCrgoBCnue9Yqhqd7dgKiEDt4HocC%20xpLhOVo2mwHDUA68jviwQA).

Comment: I don't really understand the problem with your refactored approach. `dataIndex` correctly looks up keys of `T` (`Person`). What am I missing?

Comment: Look at my first code snippet, `interface MyColumn<T extends Recordable> extends Column<T> { ... }`, `keyof T` is actually of type `string`, but in TS compiler, it's `string | number | undefined`, how can I do it to make the TS compiler correctly infer `keyof T` as `string`?

Comment: I see, you'd expect `keyof T` to be only `string` because you defined the keys of `Recordable` as such, right? The problem is that indexing by numbers and symbols is a substet of indexing by strings. So `const r: Recordable = { 5: true, [Symbol()]: 42 };` is actually valid and therefore `keyof` `T extends Recordable` is not only `string`. Does that answer your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few facts you might have to consider. In your playground you changed the `Person` type to `interface`. Interface cannot be explicit about index types that means you have to use a `type`.

If you want to use the `interface` you will need to add a index signature like `[key: string]: ...` but I guess that is not want you want. Hence for your example you might stick to `type`.

Further, look at the definition of `Record`. It is `type Record<K extends string | number | symbol, T> = { [P in K]: T; }`. If you define the `dataIndex` without the `symbol` it cannot be overridden with the `keyof` Operator. Therefore you will need add `symbol` to the `dataIndex`. I provided you an example. Hope that helps.

```js
type Person = {
    name: string;
    age: number;
}
type Recordable = Record<string, number | string | boolean>;
interface Column<T extends Recordable> {
    data: T;
    dataIndex?: string | number | symbol;
}
interface MyColumn<T extends Recordable> extends Column<T> {
    dataIndex: keyof T;
}
const jack: MyColumn<Person> = {
    data: { name: 'Jack', age: 1 },
    dataIndex: 'age',
};
```

Edit:
[Here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgArQM4HsTIN4BQyyIcAthAFzIZhSgDmA3EcnA1SQK5kBG0LYhxAATaAH5qteiGYEAvgQJgAngAcUAJQgIsUEXF4AbFAF5k23foA80xgBoadRsgA%203PtDfJeWLCbgQAD4WAlBIWEQUAGF-HhBrABVkCAAPSFEMCx09A2MIIPxWAzA4akTBZBK4AElRNMknGQZvEB5%20KG8MFT5-FkUw8Gh4JGQAWRVYo3iklPSITOyrPJNCtIyRLKmZxMLCYmq6sVTqAGsIFSwYZAqFJQB6e7nyNRNkAEZldRR0KGwQRLfZDmVDABCnay-f6Oc6Xa5QnAhJS6EC0ZAIAAWcCgqCgWDU1Am2zICQRAO%20hXM%20yqcFK1DwJHInAA5AApRCnZmOdicd7IeT2Yq02r1E7IZk8rkKUKPZ5kV4oABMADpPqoNGhsWBgHAjLj8RhZusFps0GCIWTHMzSBRmUFKeNJnESUkkQQUWi1FqdUZolicXiCZqoNrdfq1IbQeDIZgcFabRA7Q7qdV6YyKNQ2RzmfzBQdhUc0pmE1L5DKnmkXm8VYqCDAuCAENqcMgOGA-djw8SEsljYsoxbYyB40ykwAKVM3ACUhKd0xduyKxCgEDAXCguGp%20bpNNKeeIyFlh1FxdHbCyAFF0lBEGBrLCrjdHHZZEF99uRcdT7bHLKL1A8SgcogWZF8GBzYAshALAwHPDBgAYUh8mQMAsBQkCrzoW97wuR9EmfZxX1YMs7jbDsA3xbtIXNGM-jjcUS28CUOHHBkE0zdlwS5NgOGoPl5CnFggA) is a fixed example of your update

Comment: I had refactored the code, and updated it at the bottom of the question. However, I encountered additional confusing issues when using it within the function. Could you explain the possible reasons for this problem?

Comment: You are using the `Extract` wrong. Here is a fixed example. It incorporates my suggestions in respect of you changes

Comment: Ok, I'll modify my code. Thx.